# Does Task.Run scale as well as using Tasks from example WebApi?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

We have alot of requests in our system so we use Tasks with WebApi. On some places we have high requirements on speed so we cant wait for the Task to complete, I have created a Worker for this. It creates a nested container so that Entity frameworks DbContext wont get disposed etc. But it looks like Task.Run spawns a new thread for each time, how well will this scale?

```
public class BackgroundWorker<TScope> : IBusinessWorker<TScope>, IRegisteredObject where TScope : class
{
    private readonly IBusinessScope<TScope> _scope;
    private bool _started;
    private bool _stopping;

    public BackgroundWorker(IBusinessScope<TScope> scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    public void Run(Func<TScope, Task> action)
    {
        if(_stopping) throw new Exception("App pool is recycling, cant queue work");
        if(_started) throw new Exception("You cant call Run multiple times");

        _started = true;

        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

        Task.Run(() =>
            action(_scope.EntryPoint).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                _scope.Dispose();
                HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
            }));
    }

    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        _stopping = true;

        if(immediate)
            HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    }
}
```

Used like

```
backgroundWorker.Run(async ctx => await ctx.AddRange(foos).Save());
```

If I google they all end up using `Task.Run` but doesn't that kill the purpose?

**Update:** 
Did a test

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

_businessWorker.Run(async ctx => {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", guid, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await Task.Delay(1);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", guid, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
});
```

This outputs

```
3bdbe90b-c31e-4709-95d8-f7516210b0ac: 17
3bdbe90b-c31e-4709-95d8-f7516210b0ac: 9
6548fd26-d209-4427-9a91-40fc30aa509e: 15
6548fd26-d209-4427-9a91-40fc30aa509e: 19
7411b043-4fae-44bf-b93f-4273a532afa1: 7
7411b043-4fae-44bf-b93f-4273a532afa1: 17
```

Which indicates that `Task.Run` actually works like i think it should

With real DB code it looks like this

```
a939713d-d728-46c9-be33-aa57704cf242: 19 <--
a939713d-d728-46c9-be33-aa57704cf242: 19 <-- Used same for entire work
7e588a42-afd0-4ab5-ba6b-f8520c889cde: 7
7e588a42-afd0-4ab5-ba6b-f8520c889cde: 19 <-- Reused first works thread when work #2 continued
6f3b067f-f478-43f9-8411-8142b449c28b: 8
6f3b067f-f478-43f9-8411-8142b449c28b: 18
```

**update:**
Tried Luaan's approach, seems to work with Tasks spawned from EntityFramework or WebApi HttpClient, but with manual Tasks etc like below it does not work well, some are executed some are not. With `Task.Run` all are executed

```
_businessWorkerFactory().Run(async ctx =>
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", guid, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        completion.SetResult(true);
    });

    await completion.Task;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", guid, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Run` schedules the task to run on a thread pool thread. The same thread pool that handles requests.

On an ASP.NET application, sending work to the thread pool steals threads that might be necessary to handle requests.

Given your requirements, I think you would be better queuing that work to another service/process using something like MSMQ.

Comment: My understanding of WebApis implementation of Tasks is that it will release that thread when doing idle work like I/O (database etc). Will Task.Run do the same? Or is WebAPI doing something different under the hood to achieve this?

Comment: You're correct for I/O, where the real work is not done in any thread - there's only a thread to receive the completed work. `Task.Run` is for CPU work, which is bad for web applications, specially those that need rapid responses.

Comment: By the way, using `async-await`, because allocates and uses a state machine, is slower that blocking code. On a web application, using `async-await` is good for releasing threads to handle more concurrent requests. Overall, all requests combined will be quicker, be each one will be slower.

Comment: So Task.Run will not release thread to app pool when a await inside it happens? That is bad, we have huge load on our system, this worker will spawn work atleast 10 times a second. And most of the work (In relation to CPU time) is I/O work. Is there any ready to use code that I can replace Task.Run with to work more like WebAPI?

Comment: @Anders It will release the thread, that's not the worry. The question is, why are you using `Task.Run` in the first place if you *are* doing asynchronous I/O work?

Comment: This is a Transfer booking system (Transfer from Airport to Accomodation etc). When a user does availability search I need to mark each result with a Guid and save the result to our database. The Guid is then used when the user does the actual reservation. We need todo this because the third party API has so strange booking keys plus we cant expose the third party API keys to our consuming systems. For speed I need to save the result without the request to be waiting for it

Comment: It will release the thread to grab another one. Total released threads = 0. Context switches = 2.

Comment: Thats because Task.Delay(1) will continue before the ThreadPool has given back Thread to the pool. I did the same test with the actual code with DB I/O and for some runs it reused the thread.

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Run` doesn't *spawn* a new thread - it borrows one from the thread pool (assuming the thread pool task scheduler - there's different schedulers, and you can write your own as well). When you use `await` inside of `Task.Run`, it will still work as usual - freeing the thread pool thread until a callback is posted.

However, exactly for that reason, there's little point in using `Task.Run` for I/O work. If you have asynchronous I/O to do, just do it - it will work exactly the same, without requiring a context switch. You *must* make it asynchronous though - if it's just blocking code, you're taking up valuable threads from the thread pool.

Note that you don't *need* for an asynchronous request to finish. If the asynchronous action you are performing doesn't need too much time to setup (that is, it returns the `Task` almost immediately, even though it isn't finished), you can just call it:

```
public async Task SomeAsync()
{
  var request = new MyRequest();

  await request.MakeRequestAsync();

  ...
}

public void Start()
{
  var task = SomeAsync();

  // Now the task is started, and we can use it for future reference. Or just wire up
  // some error handling continuations etc. - though it's usually a better idea to do that
  // within SomeAsync directly.
}
```

Comment: I cant have the HTTP request wait for the work do be done, for speed requirements

Comment: @Anders I didn't say anything about waiting - you don't have to *wait* on an asynchronous request. You can fire-and-forget, or better, wire up a manual continuation on the task.

Comment: Task.Run is doing that for me, plus it releases the Thread when going idle. For concurrent resaons this is exactly what I want because most time during that background worker will be wating for database to insert rows

Comment: @Anders `Task.Run` means an unnecessary indirection - you borrow a thread-pool thread just to give it up almost immediately. You're probably spending more CPU-time on the context switches than on any work. My solution is the same in response time as long as you are indeed only doing asynchronous I/O, without the extraneous thread pool thread.

Comment: No the work is mixed. But most of the CPU time is handled in SQL

Comment: @Anders CPU time in SQL doesn't matter - from the C#-code perspective, it's just I/O work; you're simply making an asynchronous I/O request to the SQL server. What the SQL server does with that request is of no importance to your C# code. The only problem would be if you didn't issue that as an asynchronous request - but that should be easy to fix, the asynchronous APIs are all there.

Comment: I meant CPU time as time, most of the wait in my background work is waiting for SQL to complete, its not code executed in C#

Comment: If i remove the SQL wait and just have a Task.Delay it will not continue if i dont have Task.Run so your method seems unsafe

Comment: @Anders It works just fine with `Task.Delay` for me - there really isn't a reason why it wouldn't. Can you try reproducing the issue in some minimal example and posting that?